# Toilets in Albion

Tags: albion

Per a discussion of the earliest toilets in video games, [it was claimed that the 1995 game Albion had two types in it](http://www.intelligent-artifice.com/2003/10/toilets_in_game.html): Human ones and giant ones for the cat-people. However, the website doesn't have illustrations of this. Does anyone have a second source for this, preferably with illustrations of each type?

Comment: We're not really a place to ask for sourcing things from the internet. Those count as recommendations, and gather link only answers, which we really don't like.

Comment: We ARE a source from the internet. It seems likely for example that one of our users still owns a copy of the game and can collect screen captures.  Do not see how it could be considered a recommendation question...

Comment: @cazc_941 He's *literally* asking us to find a picture that meets his criteria! That's either a) a service request, and off-topic, or b) a request for us to find something, somewhere in the internet, that meets his criteria, which is *also* off-topic. Which one it is doesn't matter; it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is a human toilet, and looks fairly conventional:

[image: toilet]

The giant one you're talking about is likely the following:

[image: plant toilet]

Source: [Albion Wiki](http://albionworld.wikia.com/wiki/Dji-Fadh#Products).

It's described by the following:

> Giant plant toilets process fecal material rapidly and almost without odor. They only need to be watched that they don't grow too large.